# How to merge multiple pandas dataframes into one original dataframe in the most efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to merge 4 pandas dataframes into one original dataframe in the most efficient way?
Below shows the original dataframe `df` whose 4 columns `CC1`, `CC2`, `CC3` and `CC4` need to be updated with the respective columns from `df1`, `df2`, `df3` and `df4`.

The common columns for all dataframes are `TD` and `PD`.

**EDIT**

df

```
TD   PD  CC1    CC2    CC3    CC4    A     B     C
10   1   Null   Null   Null   Null   1     1     0
10   2   Null   Null   Null   Null   0     1     1
10   3   Null   Null   Null   Null   Null  2     Null
20   1   Null   Null   Null   Null   Null  0     1
20   4   Null   Null   Null   Null   2     Null  Null
30   1   Null   Null   Null   Null   4     0     2
30   3   Null   Null   Null   Null   8     Null  5
30   5   Null   Null   Null   Null   Null  1     1
40   2   Null   Null   Null   Null   0     0     0
```

df1

```
TD   PD   CC1
10   2     0
20   1     5
20   4     2
30   3    10
```

df2

```
TD   PD   CC2
10   1     15
10   2     10
20   4     20
```

df3

```
TD   PD   CC3
10   3     0
20   4     5
30   1     9
```

df4

```
TD   PD   CC4
20   4     0
30   1     15
30   3     20
```

Expected output after merge is as shown below:

df

```
TD   PD  CC1    CC2    CC3    CC4   A      B     C
10   1   Null   15    Null   Null   1      1     0
10   2    0     10    Null   Null   0      1     1
10   3   Null  Null    0     Null   Null   2     Null
20   1    5    Null   Null   Null   Null   0     1
20   4    2     20     5      0     2      Null  Null
30   1   Null  Null    9      15    4      0     2
30   3    10   Null   Null    20    8      Null  5
30   5   Null   Null   Null  Null   Null   1     1
40   2   Null   Null   Null  Null   0      0     0
```

Here the other extra columns in `df` (`A`, `B` and `C`) remain unaffected. 
Also the number of total rows in df1, df2, df3 and df4 does not equal to number of rows in df. How to achieve this in the fastest possible way and can it be done in just one statement or 4 different statements will have to be used here?

Any help deeply appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in list comprehension for create `MultiIndex` by `TD` and `PD` used for outer join by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
dfnew = pd.concat([x.set_index(['TD', 'PD']) for x in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()
print (dfnew)
   TD  PD   CC1   CC2  CC3   CC4
0  10   1   NaN  15.0  NaN   NaN
1  10   2   0.0  10.0  NaN   NaN
2  10   3   NaN   NaN  0.0   NaN
3  20   1   5.0   NaN  NaN   NaN
4  20   4   2.0  20.0  5.0   0.0
5  30   1   NaN   NaN  9.0  15.0
6  30   3  10.0   NaN  NaN  20.0


df = df.combine_first(dfnew)
```

EDIT: Error means there are duplicates in combinations `TD`, `PD`.

```
#changed data for simulate error
print (df1)
   TD  PD  CC1
0  10   2    0
1  20   4    5 <- duplicates
2  20   4    2 <- duplicates
3  20   4   10 <- duplicates
```

One idea is remove duplicated rows, so in output is only first value:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
dfnew = pd.concat([x.drop_duplicates(['TD','PD']).set_index(['TD', 'PD']) 
                   for x in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()
print (dfnew)
   TD  PD  CC1   CC2  CC3   CC4
0  10   1  NaN  15.0  NaN   NaN
1  10   2  0.0  10.0  NaN   NaN
2  10   3  NaN   NaN  0.0   NaN
3  20   4  5.0  20.0  5.0   0.0 <- first value 5
4  30   1  NaN   NaN  9.0  15.0
5  30   3  NaN   NaN  NaN  20.0
```

Another idea is aggregated, e.g. by `sum`:

```
dfnew = pd.concat([x.groupby(['TD', 'PD']).sum() for x in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()
print (dfnew)
   TD  PD   CC1   CC2  CC3   CC4
0  10   1   NaN  15.0  NaN   NaN
1  10   2   0.0  10.0  NaN   NaN
2  10   3   NaN   NaN  0.0   NaN
3  20   4  17.0  20.0  5.0   0.0 <- summed values - 17
4  30   1   NaN   NaN  9.0  15.0
5  30   3   NaN   NaN  NaN  20.0
```

Comment: A lot better than merging 4 times. +1

Comment: `@jezrael` what if the number of rows in original `df` are more than all the rows in all 4 other dfs combined? Will this solution be still effective? Also what if there are other columns also in original df?

Comment: @Prachi - Can you change solution for this sittutation?

Comment: `@jezrael` I have editted my question. can you please have a look and provide the solution now?

Comment: @Prachi - Can you check edited answer? There was renamed new DataFrame and also added last row of code.

Comment: `@jezrael` I dont know why but its giving me the following error: `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!` Earlier also i was trying a solution based on similar lines as given by you and i was getting this same error and now also. Can u plz have a look?

Comment: @Prachi - Problem are dupliciates in some values in `dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]`. It means like `20   1     5` in `df1` is changed to `20   4    5`. So there are 2 rows with `20,4` values. How should be processed this situtation?